# Tomcat 7 session cookie path

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I'm having a huge problem with my application and Tomcat 7. My application needs to set session cookie to "/" path instead of "/context" path. In tomcat 6 it was a matter of adding another property to Connector (emptySessionPath="true") and Tomcat 7 doesn't recognize this thing. I know that Servlet 3.0 spec allows to configure it on per-context basis, but I couldn't make it work with Tomcat 7. It still adds the context path instead of "/".

I will be very grateful for the receipt on how to do it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Juts put the `sessionCookiePath="/"` attribute into your context.xml root node:

`<Context ... sessionCookiePath="/" > ... </Context>`

Comment: See further http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration

Comment: @Vadim Thanks a lot.You saved my day.

Comment: Just remember that this might cause session fixation issues 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes