# Pass parameters between servlets recovered in the second Servlet by request.getParameter()

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my jsp I have a form that contains :

```
<form name="myForm" action="/ServletOne">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password"/>
</form>
```

In ServletTwo, I have :

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

At the end of ServletOne, I need to redirect to ServletTwo.
So I tried :

```
String redirectURI =  "/ServletTwo?"+ request.getQueryString();
response.sendRedirect(redirectURI);
```

But request.getQueryString() returns null.
So How could I redirect to "ServletTwo" without losing username and password parameters, knowing that ServletOne and ServletTwo are not in the same web appplication. And I don't have the right to modify the code of ServletTwo.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right following code in servletone:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ServletTwo").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I tried this :         getServletContext().getContext("/mysecondwebapp").getRequestDispatcher("/ServletTwo").forward(request, response);

Is there a difference between what I did and your response ?

Comment: Yes both have different redirections

Comment: check this out for details- http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/06/java-servlet-redirect-vs-forward.html

Comment: If you got the answer then just rate my answer, so it can help other also. Thanks

Comment: I used :
   getServletContext().getContext("/mysecondwebapp").getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet‌​Two").forward(request, response); because ServletTwo (which is in mysecondwebapp) is in not in the same webapp as ServletOne. Is this correct please ?

Comment: You should try and tell that its working in your case or not.

Comment: By default your case connot be achieved. You need to configure Tomcat first to enable exposing the **ServletContext** of the current webapp to other webapps. This is to be done by setting the **crossContext** attribute of **context.xml** to true.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Reffer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435678/does-requestdispatcher-work-over-multiple-webapps-in-one-servlet-container