# How getRequestDispatcher will work for servlet in different project in same server?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, requestdispatcher

In servlet we can use requestdispatcher and it will forward from one servlet to another servlet with same session in same project.but if i am using different project getRequestDispatcher is not working.its giving 404 error.because its appending servlet name before the url. how can i achieve getRequestDispatcher in different project in same server?

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/v1/status1/toreply1"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

In same project getRequestDispatcher working fine. but in different project its not working ?can anyone explain why its happening ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve getRequestDispatcher in different project on same server.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273223/1428052

It works on same server for different project by using 
**getServletContext().getContext()** method.

You can follow below steps for detail implementation.

First you need to make changes in below file

(Windows) C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\context.xml
Set value of crossContext to true.

**context.xml**

```
<Context crossContext="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

Please note that **crossContext="true"**.

Suppose you have two web applications with name *InterServletComm1* and *InterServletComm2*
having servlets *Servlet1* and *Servlet1* in each web application respectively. Then the code in each servlets goes as follows:

**Servlet1.java**

```
package interServletComm1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Servlet1
 */
@WebServlet("/Servlet1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Servlet1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        request.setAttribute("name", "WebApp1");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext().getContext("/InterServletComm2");
        RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet2");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**Servlet2.java**

```
package interServletComm2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Servlet2
 */
@WebServlet("/Servlet2")
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Servlet2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
        pw.println("This is web application 2.");
        pw.println("<br>The value received from web application one is: " + name);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Above code sends attribute *name* from *InterServletComm1* and it is received in *InterServletComm2*.
Please let me know if this answer is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `ServletContext` of the other web application to get the `RequestDispatcher`. The other context can be looked up by `ServletContext#getContext(String uri)`:

```
ServletContext otherContext = request.getServletContext().getContext("/other");
RequestDispatcher rd = otherContext.getRequestDispatcher("/v1/status1/toreply1");
```

Comment: otherContext is giving null when we are giving the context path of other project. for the same project context its working fine

Comment: The serlvet container is allowed to return null for security reasons: (...) In a security conscious environment, the servlet container may return null for a given URL. (...). So maybe you can configure somewhere if cross-context lookup should be possible. Depends on the servlet container you're using I think.

Comment: where we have to enable crossContext="true" in tomcat. Thanks advance